# MockMVC Test reports does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, inner classes annotated with @Configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit

I am trying to call my ajax method via a Junit test case. I have referred to a truck load of SO questions to get to this point. But still I am getting

`TestMockMVC does not declare any static, non-private, non-fin
al, inner classes annotated with @Configuration.`

My AJAX call is

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/saveEntityAjax", "/modifyEntityAjax" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String saveOrUpdateEntityAjax(
        @RequestParam(value = "id") String id,
        @RequestParam(value = "number") String number, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
```

My Junit Test case is

```
package test.controllers;

import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import com.mnox.database.pojo.wrapper.v2.VehicleMasterPojoWrapper.VehiclePurpose;

@Configuration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TestMockMVC {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).apply(springSecurity()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1CreateClient() {
        SaveOrUpdateVehicleAjaxRequest vehicle = new SaveOrUpdateVehicleAjaxRequest("123", "KA-02-1234", 12,
                VehiclePurpose.MAIN_VEHICLE.name(), "some alias");
        try {
            MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/saveVehicleAjaxMethod")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andReturn();
            mvcResult.getModelAndView();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class SaveOrUpdateEntityAjaxRequest {
        private String id;
        private String number;

        public SaveOrUpdateEntityAjaxRequest(String id, String number) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.number = number;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        public void setNumber(String number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

    }

}
```

I am getting the following errors

```
INFO : org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [test.controllers.TestMockMVC]: TestMockMVC does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, inner classes annotated with @Configuration.
INFO : org.springframework.test.context.web.WebTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
INFO : org.springframework.test.context.web.WebTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@7f3b84b8, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@57a3af25, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@2b662a77, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@7f0eb4b4, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@5c33f1a9, org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener@1623b78d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@c8c12ac, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@6adbc9d]
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@3eb25e1a: startup date [Mon Sep 11 13:11:05 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@3eb25e1a: startup date [Mon Sep 11 13:11:05 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
```

Edit : Jar's I am using are

```
spring-boot-test-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar  
spring-security-test-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar    
spring-test-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar       
spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
```

Edit : My folder structure is

```
src/main/java/test/controllers/TestMockMVC.java
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml
```

**Edit :**
I have a partial answer. I have modified my code to solve the issue reported in this question. Although I am stuck at a different point, I am answering the question partially.

**CHANGE 1**

```
@Configuration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({
        // "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml"
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml",
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml" })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TestMockMVC {

    @Autowired
    FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity(springSecurityFilterChain)).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1CreateClient() {
        SaveOrUpdateEntityAjaxRequest vehicle = new SaveOrUpdateEntityAjaxRequest("123", "KA-02-1234");
        MvcResult mvcResult = null;
        try {
            MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/saveEntityAjaxMethod")
                    .content(new Gson().toJson(vehicle).getBytes()).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            mvcResult = mvc.perform(request).andReturn();
            mvcResult.getModelAndView();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**CHANGE 2**

In my servlet-context.xml I added the following lines.

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <!-- properties -->
    </bean>
```

Exception I am getting now

```
INFO : org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet '': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet '': initialization completed in 67 ms
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.getFilters(FilterChainProxy.java:223)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269)
    at org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionTestUtils.java:307)
    at org.springframework.security.test.web.support.WebTestUtils.findFilter(WebTestUtils.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.test.web.support.WebTestUtils.getSecurityContextRepository(WebTestUtils.java:57)
    at org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors$SecurityContextRequestPostProcessorSupport.save(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.java:434)
    at org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors$TestSecurityContextHolderPostProcessor.postProcessRequest(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.java:511)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.postProcessRequest(MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.java:686)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:137)
    at test.controllers.TestMockMVC.test1CreateClient(TestMockMVC.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: And what is n't clear about that message. You are running a test but have no configuration for that test, which is exactly what the exception is telling you. Also stop mixing Spring Versions (4.1 and 3.1) unless you want to run into hard to debug issues. You also seem to use Spring Boot and try very hard not to use Spring Boot in your test.

Comment: Added the error messages from the console, also removed SpringBoot, same error. Also added my folder structure. Which xml file should I refer to and how ?

Comment: You can remove the tag, fact is you are still using Spring Boot. You have a starter class which you should load (and I assume that that also loads your xml files).

Comment: Nope, thats the issue, how do I load the xml files ?

Comment: Then why do you have Spring Boot dependencies on your classpath... Just specify the xml file to load in your `@ContextConfiguration`.

Comment: I made modifications based on your hints. Now I am facing a different issue.

Comment: You shouldn't add a bean with that name. Spring Security should be setup correctly in one of those xml files you load.